# Decorate an input tag with an icon class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter-bootstrap, how do I decorate my input tag with an icon?

I've tried:

```
<p class="icon-search"><input type="submit" value="search" /></p>​
```

and:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="search" class="icon-search" /></p>​
```

But nothing seems to work. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlecTaylor/CsjbB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `<input>` for the icons, so you must be looking for that `<button>` code :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i> search</button>
```

Just scroll [the doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) a bit.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/CsjbB/1/) (the demo is without the `.btn` class, you may want to try with it)